What are the current theories on what causes the sunflower sea star wasting disease?
There's a prion disease that has wiped out 97% of sunflower starfish, and the only thing I can find about it is there's a small subsection of the starfish who are genetically immune.

Well, if it's known to be a prion disease (is it? What is your source for that?) then that's kind of the "cause" in itself, what exactly do you mean by "cause"?

The Wikipedia page indicates cause unknown, thought to be multifactorial.

https://marine.ucsc.edu/data-products/sea-star-wasting/
